# Apache rewrite rule only working with full domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, googlebot

I'm trying to serve googlebot a static version of my JS app.

I'm using the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.html [L]
```

But its just serving index.html. If I change it to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/%1.html [L]
```

I get the following in my address bar:

http://example.com/somplace.html?_escaped_fragment_=/someplace

But I don't want to reload the page, I just want to serve the html file.

I've asked my hosting company, but they say its not their problem. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Rackspace Cloud server.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: What about `RewriteRule ^$ /%1.html? [L]` ?

Comment: @JustinLurman - same same